# How to add code after every `\chapter` in ConTeXt, but not after TOC?

Tags: sectioning, context

I used this code to place a macro that will appear immediately after every chapter title:

```
\setuphead[chapter][after={\dropcontents}]
```

This works, but is strangely also adding the macro after the TOC title, and even stranger, also after `\title`.

How can I get this code to appear after every chapter, but not after the TOC and `\title`?

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example? Wrt `\title` or `\starttitle ... \stoptitle`, it's just because it inherits setups from `\chapter` and a simple `\setuphead[title][after=]` cleans it from your custom macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

```
\setuphead[title][after=]
```

### Long answer

In ConTeXt, sections and their unnumbered variants, e.g. `\chapter` and `\title` (see [the corresponding ConTeXt Wiki page](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Titles#Default) for additional info),  are coupled, so the latter will inherit setups from the former, but not the other way around. And, as you possibly realize, `\completecontent` include a `title` head, so your macro will show up there too. So the solution is to unset `after` and other options if you want your titles (or unnumbered heads) to be different.

**Examples:**

```
\setuppapersize[A6]
%Chapters and titles will have a message below
\setuphead[chapter][after={\emph{\red Look at me!}\blank}]
\starttext
\startchapter[title=\type{after=...} set]
\input jojomayer
\stopchapter
\starttitle[title=Open oyes wide]
\input jojomayer
\stoptitle
\stoptext
```

[image]

```
%Only titles will include a message
\setuppapersize[A6]
\setuphead[title][after={\emph{\red Look at me!}\blank}]
\starttext
\startchapter[title=No \type{after} set]
\input jojomayer
\stopchapter
\starttitle[title=Open oyes wide]
\input jojomayer
\stoptitle
\stoptext
```

[image]